# SAS Mainframe to read CSV column names automatically

Tags: csv, import, sas, mainframe

Is there any way to read read CSV column names automatically in Mainframe environment as PROC IMPORT is not supported in Mainframe? Tried the below code it is working in PC SAS but not in Mainframe SAS.

```
      FILENAME FILEIN "ABC.CUST.FILE" DISP=SHR RECFM=V;

      DATA VARNAMES;
      INFILE FILEIN DELIMITER=',' DSD OBS=1 LRECL=32000;
      INPUT VARNAME $ @@;
      RUN;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know any particular reason why that general method wouldn't work on mainframe, but I'm not a mainframe expert.  Can you post what's not working about it?

Comment: The above code is taking default length as 8 and not able to identify comma as delimiter. As of now I cannot provide the exact example because I have some problem in Mainframe environment. I will update with the exact problem sooner.

Comment: Default length of 8 should be the case in both mainframe and PC SAS.  You need to provide a length statement for `varname` before the input (or `:$32.` in the input statement).  Comma should work, perhaps it's not the same comma (some sort of unicode like issue)?

Comment: @Joe Thanks Joe. It is working now by using 32. Already tried using Length but it was not working because of some mainframe access issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PROC IMPORT on PC and copy the generated datastep code to mainframe.